# Calling PHP file from JS file and insert into database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, oracle

I am doing a project at my faculty and basically we are replicating a PAC-MAN game. I'm trying to insert a highscore into an Oracle database through a PHP file, names insertintotable.ph and tried to use Ajax so I can update it. The problem is nothing happens.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function score(s, type) { 

var scoreBefore = (SCORE / 10000) | 0;

SCORE += s;
if (SCORE === 0) { 
    $('#score span').html("00");
} else { 
    $('#score span').html(SCORE);
}

var scoreAfter = (SCORE / 10000) | 0;
if (scoreAfter > scoreBefore) { 
    lifes( +1 );
}


if (SCORE > HIGHSCORE) { 
    HIGHSCORE = SCORE;
    if (HIGHSCORE === 0) { 
        $('#highscore span').html("00");
    } else { 
        $.ajax({
    url: '/inserintotable.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        score: HIGHSCORE.val(),
    }
}).done(function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
    }
}

if (type && (type === "clyde" || type === "pinky" || type === "inky" || type === "blinky") ) { 
    erasePacman(); 
    eraseGhost(type); 
    $("#board").append('<span class="combo">' + SCORE_GHOST_COMBO + '</span>');
    $("#board span.combo").css('top', eval('GHOST_' + type.toUpperCase() + '_POSITION_Y - 10') + 'px');
    $("#board span.combo").css('left', eval('GHOST_' + type.toUpperCase() + '_POSITION_X - 10') + 'px');
    SCORE_GHOST_COMBO = SCORE_GHOST_COMBO * 2;
} else if (type && type === "fruit") { 
    $("#board").append('<span class="fruits">' + s + '</span>');
    $("#board span.fruits").css('top', (FRUITS_POSITION_Y - 14) + 'px');
    $("#board span.fruits").css('left', (FRUITS_POSITION_X - 14) + 'px');
}
```

}

and here is the php file:

```
      <?php

  // Query pentru crearea tabelei : CREATE TABLE HighScores (NumeUser varchar2(25),Scor int NOT NULL);
  session_start();
  $userName = isset($_SESSION['userName']) ? $_SESSION['userName'] : NULL;
  $conn = oci_connect('vladut', 'LAB11', 'localhost/XE');
  if (!$conn) {
     $e = oci_error();
     trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
 }

  $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'INSERT INTO HighScores VALUES(:user, :scor)');
  //$user=_$GET["username"]; //din jquery primeste username-ul
  $scor=_$POST["score"]; //idem
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':user', $userName);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':scor', $scor);

  oci_execute($stid); 

  oci_free_statement($stid);
  oci_close($conn);

  ?>
```

Comment: `_$POST` that is definitely a typo.

Answer (score 0):

In your php file check for line `14` you're using `_$POST["score"]` which is incorrect. You must modify this line `14` code with this

```
$scor=$_POST["score"]; //idem
```

Also you can use the following code I added json_decode function

```
<?php
// Query pentru crearea tabelei : CREATE TABLE HighScores (NumeUser varchar2(25),Scor int NOT NULL);
session_start();
$userName = isset($_SESSION['userName']) ? $_SESSION['userName'] : NULL;
$conn = oci_connect('vladut', 'LAB11', 'localhost/XE');

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES) , E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'INSERT INTO HighScores VALUES(:user, :scor)');
// $user=_$GET["username"]; //din jquery primeste username-ul
$score = json_decode($_POST['score']);
$scor = $score->{'score'}; //idem
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':user', $userName);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':scor', $scor);
oci_execute($stid);
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: That's right. I've changed that, but still nothing happens.

Comment: @VlăduțCojocariu I understand in your JS can you also remove / from url so it will look like this `url: 'inserintotable.php',`

Comment: I've changed a little bit and looked through the console. The php is called, but the problem is that my POST returns a 404: not found. I'm figuring out that there's maybe a problem of how I am sending the variable HIGHSCORE, but I don't know exactly how to change it.

Comment: This is because your php file path is not correct when you correct this path you code will work can you share the current paths

Comment: The path is correct, the filename had a typo. Now it doesn't return any errors, but still it doesn't insert into the table.

Comment: Check for the `$userName` this time I am sure its blank at this stage can you verify

Comment: @VlăduțCojocariu I added json decode function in your php can you try the updated answer and check if its inserting values or not?